# maya saving menu info (frame range)

Tags: menu, maya

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SLf1.png)I have a menu that has multiple frame ranges for different objects being animated. I need that menu to save that frame range everytime its closed and reopened. Is it possible to save out data to an external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to save out data externally. Probably one of the easiest ways is using the `json` module:

```
import os
import json


path = "PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/data.json"


def save_data(frame_range):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(frame_range))


def load_data():
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, "r") as f:
            return json.loads(f.read())


save_data([1, 100])

stored_range = load_data()

print stored_range
# Output: [1, 100]
```

In this case it's dumping a `list`, but it supports much more (dictionaries, nested data structures)

Another alternative is saving data with the `pickle` module:

```
import pickle


path = "PATH/TO/YOUR/FILE/data.p"


def save_data(frame_range):
    with open(path, "w") as f:
        f.write(pickle.dumps(frame_range))


save_data([1, 100])
```

You can also use `cpickle` to export as a binary format.

In Maya itself, you can save settings directly to the user's preferences:

```
cmds.optionVar(iv=("frameStart", 1))
cmds.optionVar(iv=("frameEnd", 100))
```

You can also simply store a `json` string directly in `cmds.optionVar` for more complex data structures.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was looking into pickle but that requires a path, right? I need the menu to be used by multiple users and load the frame range that's in the textfield the same as what they enter before. .Also it needs to be rewrite every time number are changed.

Comment: `pickle` itself doesn't require a path but you pass it to the file you're writing to, just like `json`. Is this not what you're after?

Comment: I can make that work but I need it to apply to the ui every time. How do I do that?

Comment: Please edit your post and include a simple example of what you have so far. I can't help if I have no idea what framework you're using for your interface.

Comment: I add a image of my ui. I just need the variable of startframe and endframe to by save evertime the menu opens. So the menu opens, the user puts in the frame range, the frame range is saved, the menu is closed and reopened with same numbers for the frame range.

Comment: You realize there's more than one way to create a gui in Maya, right? If this is `PySide` you can simply use the `closeEvent` to save your settings then `showEvent` to load them back. You're terminology is getting confusing. You're saying "menu", but I don't see a menu bar there. Do you mean when the window closes?

Comment: Yeah I mean window.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
def saveS ():
    startFrame =  cmds.textField ('one', q= True, text = True)
    endFrame = cmds.textField ('two', q= True, text = True)
    frame= {}
    frame["start"] = startFrame
    frame["end"] = endFrame
    file2 = open ("maya/2018/scripts/test_pickle/dataCopy.json", "w")
    json.dump (frame, file2)
    file2.close()
def helpMenu():
    if(cmds.window('window1_ui',q=True,ex=True)):cmds.deleteUI('window1_ui')
    cmds.window('window1_ui')
    cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
    cmds.checkBox( label='Default' )
    cmds.textField('one', cc= 'saveS ()')
    cmds.textField('two', cc= 'saveS ()')
    json_file = open ("maya/2018/scripts/test_pickle/dataCopy.json", "r")
    frame = json.load(json_file)
    json_file.close()
    ted=frame["start"]
    cmds.textField ('one', edit= True, text = ted)
    fred=frame["end"]
    cmds.textField ('two', edit= True, text = fred)
    cmds.showWindow('window1_ui')
 helpMenu()
```

This is what I came up with. It works Thanks for your help @GreenCell.